# 401 With Indy IdHttp Digest Authentication in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, indy, digest-authentication

Trying to do a get() with Digest to a partner's web service with Delphi XE.

I have included `IdAuthenticationDigest` to the uses clause which should automatically work from what I've read - but I must be missing something because I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized.

Code:

```
begin
  // Init request:   
  IdHttp := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
  try
    idHttp.Request.ContentType := self.inputType; // 'application/xml'
    idHttp.Request.Accept := self.outputType; //'application/json';

    // Set request method:
    idHttp.Request.Method := Method; // 'Get'
    // Set username and password:
    idHttp.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    // IdHttp.Request.Username/Password also fails
    IdHttp.Request.Authentication.Username := 'xx';
    IdHttp.Request.Authentication.password := 'xx';

    IdHttp.Request.ContentLength := Length(Body);

    // Send request:
    if Method = 'GET' then
      Result := idHttp.Get(self.ServiceHost + URI)
    else
    if Method = 'POST' then
      Result := idHttp.Post(self.ServiceHost + URI, SendStream);

   finally
    idHttp.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `Request.Username` and `Request.Password` properties instead of using the `Request.Authentication` property.  Also, do not set the `Request.Method` or `Request.ContentLength` properties at all.  All three of those properties are managed by `TIdHTTP` internally.

```
  // Init request:   
  IdHttp := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
  try
    idHttp.Request.ContentType := self.inputType; // 'application/xml'
    idHttp.Request.Accept := self.outputType; //'application/json';

    // Set username and password:
    idHttp.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHttp.Request.Username := 'xx';
    IdHttp.Request.Password := 'xx';

    // Send request:
    if Method = 'GET' then
      Result := IdHttp.Get(self.ServiceHost + URI)
    else
    if Method = 'POST' then
      Result := IdHttp.Post(self.ServiceHost + URI, SendStream);
   finally
    IdHttp.Free;
   end;
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that (and the Request.Username is how I had it to start), still fails with a 401 - Resource requires authentication.

Comment: Then please provide a trace log of the actual HTTP traffic going back and forth. Either `TIdHTTP` is sending a bad Digest request, or it is not sending a Digest request at all. Use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, or one of Indy's own `TIdLog...` components, to capture that traffic.

Comment: Not sending a digest request at all.

Comment: In the `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event, is the `AuthenticationClass` parameter set to `TIdDigestAuthentication` on input? If not, then either the server is not asking for Digest in the first place (which you can verify with the `AuthInfo` parameter in that same event), or `TIdDigestAuthentication` has not actually been registered with `TIdHTTP`.

Comment: I just confirmed that `AuthenticationClass` is being set to `TIdDigestAuthentication` in the `OnSelectAuthorization` event.  The API partner I'm trying to hit claims the 2nd of the two requests that makes up a Digest request is missing.

Comment: Digest doesn't use multiple requests, unless you count the initial unauthenticated request that triggers a Digest challenge. There is only 1 request sent for a Digest challenge. NTLM, on the other hand, sends multiple requests for a challenge.

Comment: I'm sorry Remy, didn't see this, the partner says the answer to the challenge is not seen.

Comment: That is not helpful information.  Can they provide more specific details about WHAT exactly is missing?

Answer (score 4):

Add OnAuthorization event something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1Authorization(Sender: TObject;
  Authentication: TIdAuthentication; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
Authentication.Username:='user';
Authentication.Password:='passs'; 
if Authentication is TIdDigestAuthentication then
  begin
    showmessage('onAuthorization: '+Authentication.Authentication);
    TIdDigestAuthentication(IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication).Uri:=IdHTTP1.Request.URL;
    TIdDigestAuthentication(Authentication).Method := 'GET';
  end;
Handled:=true;
end;
```

Sometimes indy misses some necesary info. In my case, I'm connecting to a Tomcat server but this need the Get method when the digest params authentication info is sent.

Comment: This event is not being triggered.

Comment: Be sure that IdHttp have basicAuthentication set to false and IdHttp.Request.Authentication.Username and IdHttp.Request.Authentication.password be empty.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to set the *hoInProcessAuth* Flag, befor performing the GET.

```
idHttp.HTTPOptions := idHttp.HTTPOptions + [hoInProcessAuth];
```